# Javascript regex with quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a way to replace all appearances of `<br class="">`  with just `<br>`

I'm a complete novice with regex, but I tried:

```
str = str.replace(/<br\sclass=\"\"\s>/g, "<br>");
```

and it didn't work.

What's a proper regex to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? An empty `class` attribute does not hurt.

Comment: You almost had it: `str = str.replace(/<br\s+class=""\s*>/g, "<br>");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use a regex to do this, but rather actually parse the html and remove the classes.
This is untested, but probably works.

```
// Dummy <div> to hold the HTML string contents
var d = document.createElement("div");
d.innerHTML = yourHTMLString;

// Find all the <br> tags inside the dummy <div>
var brs = d.getElementsByTagName("br");

// Loop over the <br> tags and remove the class
for (var i=0; i<brs.length; i++) {
  if (brs[i].hasAttribute("class")) {
     brs[i].removeAttribute("class");
  }
}

// Return it to a string
var yourNewHTMLString = d.innerHTML;
```

Comment: get/set/removeAttribute are buggy in various builds of IE and are best avoided. Modifying the `className` DOM property is desirable.

Comment: Works great in Opera 11. Blows up in IE6.

Answer (score 0):

`\s` matches exactly one whitespace character. You probably want `\s*`, which will match any number (including zero) of whitespace characters, and `\s+`, which will match at least one.

```
str = str.replace(/'<br\s+class=\"\"\s*>/g, "<br>");
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is with the following

```
var s = '<br class="">';
var n = s.replace(/(.*)(\s.*)(>)/,"$1$3");
console.log(n)
```